# Connecting RS232 output of Lattice XP2 Brevia Kit to PC USB (virtual COM port over USB) using a FTDI RS232RL based board

Tags: fpga, rs232, ftdi, lattice

I have a [Lattice Brevia XP2 Kit](http://www.latticesemi.com/products/developmenthardware/developmentkits/xp2breviadevelopmentkit.cfm) (the older one that came out in 2010/2011, and the not the newer version 2). The only PC connectivity it has is through serial (rs232). I have anetbook that does not have the rs232 port, but I regularly use a [Sanguino](http://sanguino.cc) via virtual COM port over USB.  I use a [FTDI breakout board](http://www.bhashatech.com/breakout-boards/23-freeduino-usb-adapter.html) for this.

I am trying to use this FTDI board to also communciate with the XP2 kit. For this, I have wired the rs232 null modem cable supplied in the XP2 kit to the FTDI board via temporary connections using jumper cables. Here is a pic (apologies for the quality) and the wiring diagram is below it.

[image: FTDI to XP2 pic]

RS232 pin assignments on the XP2 Brevia kit:

[image]

Wiring diagram:

[image]

When I analyze this using the Advanced Serial Port Monitor utility, I see no errors and can send data without errors. I am supposed to see some headers from the Brevia XP2 board but I see nothing (no errors too).

What am I doing wrong?

Rgds,
Sushrut.

Comment: Also, just wondering - if I use a multimeter to measure the tx/rx pins of the db9 connector coming out of the xp2 kit, I should see rs232 voltage levels for data being transmitted out of the xp2 kit, right?

Comment: A multimeter is unlikely to capture the fast events. A memory oscilloscope is much more helpful.

Comment: Yes - I tried this but couldn't see any events at all in the multimeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory, the Brevia happens to have its connector backwards; it has a female connector, like DCE such as modems, but the wiring is in DTE order. The simple solution is to use the included [null modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem) cable (it looks like an extension cable but swaps pins 2 and 3) with a common [USB to RS-232 adapter](http://dx.com/p/usb-to-rs232-adapter-with-usb-extension-cable-41cm-length-24799).

The FTDI breakout module uses LVCMOS levels (1=3.3V, 0=0V) rather than [RS-232 levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_levels) which are a much wider range), and is missing the level shifting part (U3 on the Brevia). You could use it with other general I/Os by changing the pin mappings in the FPGA design. Just edit the pin constraints for your FPGA design and map the RS232_[RT]x_TTL signals elsewhere; I/O pins are equal as far as the FPGA is concerned, aside from a few dedicated to clocks, reset signals or configuration.

Comment: Thanks Yann. Can you please give me examples of " a common USB to RS-232 adapter"? Also, could you explain this statement in more detail - "You could use it with other general I/Os by changing the pin mappings in the FPGA design."?

Comment: I found these RS232 - USB interfacing boards. Would anyone have recommendations if they suit my use case? I am going to separately verify with the vendor too.

Links:
http://www.sunrom.com/usb-to-serial-rs232/usb-to-rs232-serial-uart-convertor-plug-type

http://www.sunrom.com/usb-to-serial-rs232/usb-to-rs232-converter